# How to do port forwarding/redirecting on Debian?

Tags: debian, iptables, ppp

I have two questions.

Question 1: My debian machine has interface eth3 with ip 192.168.57.28. If someone tries to connect to 192.168.57.28:1234 how do I redirect the request to another machine: 192.168.57.25:80?

Question 2: If my debian machine has two interfaces: eth3 with 192.168.57.28 and ppp0 with some dynamic IP and someone tries to connect via ppp0 on port 1234, how do I redirect the request to 192.168.57.25:80?

I have tried this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1234 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.57.25:80
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I would highly recommend reading [this tutorial](http://www.frozentux .net/documents/iptables-tutorial/) on `iptables` but the site appears to be down at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the rule looks fine, but you have to remember that packets generated in that machine do not go through PREROUTING. If said machine that holds the iptables in question needs to also redirect it's own traffic the same way, you need to put the same rule to OUTPUT. See iptables-extensions DNAT, it's valid both in OUTPUT and PREROUTING.

Another this that might come into question is filtering. Make sure you also allow said traffic to pass through the machine both ways.

Third thing is that you may also need to MASQUERADE the traffic to that destination in POSTROUTING for a route home.

I can't tell where the packets are lost based on information present. Use tcpdump to see where the packets fly.